# How to extract and count artist mentions from messy text data using AI

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning, text-extraction, large-language-model

I have a long list of responses from a poll (in this case, we've asked our Facebook community we should have at our music festival). Our goal is to count the total mentions for each artist, but the data quality is low.

Here is some sample data:

`Rena Guinn and the Gentlemen Blackwater Railroad Company`
`Mo' Mojo Music !!`
`We would love to be apart of this awesome event! Amazing!!!!!`
`The Rollin' Rust came threw at the #falldownfest last weekend  much love:) keep it up boys` 
`Luke Hess Langhorne Slim!!!!!, Sierra Hull, First Aid Kit, Jim Lauderdale (always)`

We feel the data quality is too poor for basic LDA approaches (lots of misspellings, odd phrasings) and we feel a LLM would be best at least extracting the names of artists using context.

We have found that ChatGPT and Claude are decent at the extraction tasks on small samples but can't handle the full input, and are next to worthless on the counting task. We've tried very specific and differnet prompts, but haven't been able to get a good result.

So how should I approach this problem? I'm not sure how to break this down in to prompts or substeps. I'm not sure how to do anything of this outside of a browser, and I'm a data science novice, but willing to learn some things.

Here's an example of a prompt that's not returning correct counts (off by >50% in most cases)

`The following is raw text comments copied from a poll. Count the total number of mentions in the poll and create a table that contains columns Band (a unique list of bands) and a column containing the total number of mentions. The table should cover the top 100 bands by total mentions. Use judgement and context to conform band names in to unique values (Example: The Town Pants, Town Pants, townpants are all the same band). Count completely and accurately. Now here is the raw data:`